# Prove this bound for embeddings of a number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a number field with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n=r+2s$, where $r$ denotes the number of real embeddings of $K$ and $s$ denotes the number of complex embeddings of $K$. Suppose $n$ is a fixed number. Denote by $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ the embeddings $K\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and by $\sigma_{r+1},\ldots,\sigma_{r+s}$ the embeddings $K\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (here the conjugated embeddings are not included). Let $e_i=1$ if $\sigma_i$ is real and $e_i=2$ if $\sigma_i$ is complex. I want to prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$, $\alpha \neq 0$ so that
$$|\sigma_1(\alpha)|^{e_1}<2^{r+s}\sqrt{|\Delta|} \quad \quad \mbox{and} \quad \quad
|\sigma_i(\alpha)|^{e_i}<\frac{1}{2} \: \mbox{ for } \: i>1$$

Here $\Delta$ denotes the discriminant of the field $K$. I think I could use that if $I\subset \mathcal{O}_K$ is an ideal, there is a lattice $\wedge_I$ which has volume $2^{-s}\sqrt{|\Delta|}$. However I am not sure what to do with this. Can someone help me?